# LTC3612EFE vs. LTC3612IFE

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, datasheet

I am unable to figure out what difference is between the following part numbers, poring over the data sheet has shown no discernable difference and/or no mention of what the suffixes mean although they are both listed.  Looking through Digikey pages I am also unable to exactly pin down what differences there are between the two part numbers and they even show up as an 'exact' match in siliconexpert. I am hoping someone has some sort of information on what these differences may be.

[image: Information directly from data sheet]

Is there a difference?  Is this listed somewhere?  I can see that the HFE and MPFE variants have different temperature requirements, but is there *any* difference between the EFE and IFE, and if not why are there two separate part numbers?

[LTC3612 Data sheet - last rev May '18](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc3612.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the spellcheck on poring, Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the `I` vs. `E` is explained in Note 2 on page 4:

[image]

This is the relevant text:

> Note 2: ...The LTC3612E is guaranteed to meet performance specifications
> from 0°C to 85°C junction temperature. Specifications over the
> –40°C to 125°C operating junction temperature range are assured by
> design, characterization and correlation with statistical process controls.
> The LTC3612I is guaranteed over the full –40°C to 125°C operating
> junction temperature range...

The `I` is guaranteed over the full -40°C to 125°C range, whereas the `E` is only guaranteed from 0°C to 85°C. The `E` will still work over the full range and will probably be in spec, but it is not guaranteed to be.